# Why is Wien's displacement law called "displacement" law?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, terminology, thermal-radiation

I was being taught [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) but why is it called so on asking teacher told that as it tells a variation of temperature on the displacement of wavelength
I am not convinced by the answer

Comment: The wavelength corresponding to the max energy of an object when groaned against temperature, we will observe it to be displacing left. See $\lambda_{max}$ in this image: https://images.app.goo.gl/vw3K6fg8eQDYnMeb7

Comment: Your teacher's expansion should be the other way round. The law states how the wavelength of the maximum is shifted when the temperature is changed. Wien wrote in German and used the word "verschieben" which was translated into English as "displace" but in German it has a more general meaning of "shift", perhaps "shift" would be a better word, but historically it was translated as "displacement" so we're stuck with it.

Comment: It was based on experiments, so perhaps it helps to think about what happens when you heat an object and it starts to glow. When it gets hotter, the colour of the glowing object changes (or "shifts") from red to yellow and then blue-white. When the temperature changes, there is a shift in colour (i.e. the wavelength of the maximum). It was this change that Wien described with the German word "Verschiebung" (which means "movement in one direction", "shift" or "displacement").